# Looking for specific Linear Algebra 1 exercises

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I do not know if this is the right place to do it but I am looking for theoretical Linear Algebra I exercises. Of course they can admit some calculations but more focused on theory, could be even better if they contain 6-7 questions to maybe show a theorem or whatever (I will give a couple of examples at the end).
The subjects are classic Linear Algebra 1 ones : groups, rings, fields, vector spaces, linear applications, matrixes (especially companion matrix), complex numbers, row echelon form, multilinear forms and determinants.

Example 1 : Let $\mathbb Z [i] := \mathbb Z + \mathbb Z.i = \{a + ib, \text{with } a, b ∈ \mathbb Z\} ⊂ \mathbb C$ (the Gaussian integers).

- 1. Show that $\mathbb Z [i]$ is a subring of $\mathbb C$.
- 2. Show that $\mathbb Z [i]^{\times} = \{a+ib \in \mathbb Z [i], \lvert a +ib \rvert=1\} $.
- 3. Show that $\mathbb Z [i]^{\times} = \{±1,±i\}$.
- 4. Let $w = u + iv \in \mathbb C$ and the square $C_w := [u − 1/2, u + 1/2] + i[v − 1/2, v + 1/2] ⊂ \mathbb C$. Show that $C_w$ contains at least one Gaussian integer.
- 5. Let $q \in \mathbb Z [i] - \{0\}$ a nonzero Gaussian integer and $z \in \mathbb Z [i]$ another Gaussian integer. Show that $\exists$ Gaussian integers $k,r$ such that $z = q.k + r$ and $|r| < |q|$.
- 6. Let $I \neq \{0\}$ and $I ⊂ \mathbb Z [i]$ be an ideal of $\mathbb Z [i]$. Show that $\exists q \in I −\{0\}$ of minimal module $|q|$ among all nonzero elements of I.
- 7. Show that $I = q.\mathbb Z [i] = \{q.k, k \in \mathbb Z [i]\}$.

Example 2 :
Let $\phi : U \to V$ , $\psi : V \to W$ linear applications between finite vector spaces.

1. Show that $Im(\psi \circ \phi) ⊂ Im(\psi)$.
2. Show that $ker(\phi) ⊂ ker(\psi \circ \phi)$.
3. Show that $rank(\psi \circ \phi) \leq min(rank(\psi),rank(\phi))$.
4. We suppose that $U = V = W$. Show that
   $rank(\psi \circ \phi) \geq rank(\psi) + rank(\phi) − dim(V)$.

Comment: For the ones that are actually linear algebra, try "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler or "Linear Algebra" by Friedberg Insel and Spence. However, groups and rings do not fall under the purview of what is typically called "linear algebra".

Comment: "Linear algebra done right" is so well-written that I regretted why I hadn't read it earlier the first time I saw it.

Comment: @Chady For questions on groups, rings, and fields (usually considered part of "abstract algebra"), two commonly used resources are "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Nicholson and "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote.